# element: hover for many elements: is there a shortcut?

Tags: performance, css, shortcut

I have many elements with `:hover` effect in CSS:

```
#twitterbt:hover, #googleplusbt:hover, #facebookbt:hover, #twitterfollow:hover, #googleplusfollow:hover, #facebookfollow:hover, #pinterest:hover {
    opacity: 0.7
}
```

Is there a shortcut to reduce CSS code (maybe even with a slight impact on performance)?

The only way that I think is to add a class to each element, but I don't know if is a good idea and if are there other ways.

Comment: Use a common class for everything.

Comment: Give them a common class :)

Comment: As said, give them a common class. Or you can create a selector that includes the buttons parent container (but that's debatable without your markup) - [example](https://jsfiddle.net/xqrLg7kn/)

Answer (score 2):

Give each element the same class in the HTML;

```
<div id="twitterbt" class="socialMedia"> ....
```

Then use a class selector in CSS;

```
.socialMedia:hover{
    opacity:0.7;
}
```